# starting Y axis from preferred number

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
DATA1 <- data.frame(
    Percent.houses = c(44, 44.5, 44.7, 45.8, 45.9, 45, 45.4, 45.6, 45.3),
    BUILDING.TYPE = c("wood bungalow", "brick bungalow", "glass bungalow", "wood flat", "brick flat", "glass flat", "wood house", "brick house", "glass house"),
    STRUCTURAL.MAKEUP = c("wood", "brick", "glass", "wood", "brick", "glass", "wood", "brick", "glass"))
```

I want my y axis to start from 43 and end at 53 (with ticks every 1)

I have read through past questions and solutions, and tried this

```
a <- ggbarplot(
    DATA1, 
    x = "BUILDING.TYPE" , 
    y = "Percent.houses", 
    fill = "STRUCTURAL.MAKEUP", 
    color = "black", 
    width = 0.5, 
    sort.by.groups = TRUE, 
    x.text.angle = 45, label = TRUE, label.pos = "in", lab.vjust = -0.2 + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(43, 53), breaks = seq(43, 53, by = 1))
) +
    scale_fill_manual(
        "", 
        breaks = c("wood", "brick", "glass"), 
        values = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), 
        labels = c("wood", "brick", "glass")
    )
a + font("x.text", size = 6)
```

However, this does not seem to change the y axis as required. Any help will be appreciated. Apologies, I am still very new to R.

Comment: Try moving `+ scale_y_continuous(…)` out of the `ggbarplot()` call, and instead add it as a new line similar to how you’ve added `scale_fill_manual(…)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zephryl mentioned above you need to move the `scale_y_continuous` call outside the `ggbarplot` function call. But you also need to tell ggplot not to omit values outside the range you specify. Since the bars start at zero, limiting the range to something that does not include zero will cause those values to be excluded. You can over-ride this behavior by specifying a different function of "out of bounds" values, specifically `scales::squish`. Like this:

```
a <- ggbarplot(
  DATA1, 
  x = "BUILDING.TYPE" , 
  y = "Percent.houses", 
  fill = "STRUCTURAL.MAKEUP", 
  color = "black", 
  width = 0.5, 
  sort.by.groups = TRUE, 
  x.text.angle = 45, 
  label = TRUE, 
  label.pos = "in", 
  lab.vjust = -0.2 
) +
scale_y_continuous(oob = scales::squish, 
                   limits = c(43, 53), 
                   breaks = seq(43, 53, by = 1)) +
scale_fill_manual(
  "", 
  breaks = c("wood", "brick", "glass"), 
  values = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), 
  labels = c("wood", "brick", "glass")
)
a + font("x.text", size = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

@erikor is right that simply setting limits within `scale_y_continuous()` will cause all your values to be excluded. One solution is to use the `oob` argument as they demonstrated. Another is to specify `ylim` in `coord_cartesian()`; unlike `scale_y_continuous()`, this has the effect of "zooming in" to the specified limits without removing data.

```r
library(ggpubr)

a <- ggbarplot(
    DATA1, 
    x = "BUILDING.TYPE" , 
    y = "Percent.houses", 
    fill = "STRUCTURAL.MAKEUP", 
    color = "black", 
    width = 0.5, 
    sort.by.groups = TRUE, 
    x.text.angle = 45, label = TRUE, label.pos = "in", lab.vjust = -0.2
) +
    scale_fill_manual(
        "", 
        breaks = c("wood", "brick", "glass"), 
        values = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), 
        labels = c("wood", "brick", "glass")
    ) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = 43:53) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(43, 53))

a + font("x.text", size = 6)
```

[image]